# Not Background Method called for LocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

If i  force close my app from background. then local notification come .And if  tapped on local notification my method not called when app is running in foreground.I am newer in iOS. Please Help.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Reh" object:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"

                                                        message:notification.alertBody

                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"

                                              otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];





        [alert show];


        NSLog(@"%@",notification.soundName);






        // AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1010);




        MyNotificationViewController *profile=[[MyNotificationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyNotificationViewController" bundle:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshFoeByPush" object:nil];

        self.viewController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:self.leftMenuController frontViewController:profile];        self.viewController.rightViewController=nil;
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                        animations:^{self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;} completion:nil];






        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    }
    else

    {
        NSString *tokend=     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"token"];
        if (tokend == (id)[NSNull null] || tokend.length == 0 )
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MyNotificationViewController *profile=[[MyNotificationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyNotificationViewController" bundle:nil];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshFoeByPush" object:nil];

            self.viewController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:self.leftMenuController frontViewController:profile];        self.viewController.rightViewController=nil;
            [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                            animations:^{self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;} completion:nil];


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotification != nil) {
        [self showLocalNotificationAlert:localNotification];
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{    
    [self showLocalNotificationAlert:notification];
}


-(void)showLocalNotificationAlert:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    // handle here what you want
}
```

ALSO

When local notification fire `didReceiveLocalNotification` method is called not `handleActionWithIdentifier`

And yes put your stuff in common method `-(void)showLocalNotificationAlert:(UILocalNotification *)notification` so you just needs to call

1. When app is in forground then `didReceiveLocalNotification` this will called.
2. When app is not in forground and you tapped on notification then this notification object can be get from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

---

For Remote Notification

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
NSDictionary *remoteNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (remoteNotification) {
        [self showRemoteNotificationAlert:remoteNotification];
    }
```

> Dictionary contains payload for remotenotification

And also made common method for remote notification fire and remote notification tapped.

lol

Comment: @VarunSinghal do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

When your app is killed and you tap on push notification this function will trigger;

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

you should handle it like this,

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptionsobjectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
     Parse or Do something
}
```